# Recharts Line Chart not working properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, recharts

I have some JSON having 4474 objects contained within an array which looks like:

```
data: [
 {
   "T": "2017-02-04 14:16:51",
   "Min": 0,
   "Max": 0,
   "Average": 0
 },
 {
   "T": "2017-03-27 14:51:23",
   "Min": 0,
   "Max": 0,
   "Average": 0
 },
 {
   "T": "2017-03-27 14:53:23",
   "Min": 0,
   "Max": "1,7",
   "Average": "0,1"
 },
 {
   "T": "2017-03-27 15:23:23",
   "Min": "1,6",
   "Max": "1,6",
   "Average": "1,6"
 },
............
............4473,
{
   "T": "2017-05-05 14:16:51",
   "Min": "1,3",
   "Max": "1,3",
   "Average": "1,3"
 }
];
```

I am trying to draw a line chart with T as X axis and Max as Y axis. I have written some code which looks like below:

```
let da = data.data;
let as = d3.extent(da, item => Parse(item.T)); // [Sat Feb 04 2017 14:16:51 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time), Fri May 05 2017 14:16:51 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)]
let bs =  d3.extent(da, item => item.Max); //  [0,17]

<LineChart width={1100} height={650} data={da}
            margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
         <XAxis datakey="T" scale={"time"} domain={ as } allowDataOverflowBoolean={true}/>
         <YAxis datakey="Max" scale={"linear"} type="number" domain={bs} allowDataOverflowBoolean={true}/>
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
         <Tooltip/>
        <Legend />
       <Line type="linear" dataKey="Max" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
</LineChart>
```

When I assign **as** to domain for XAxis component, it logs **domain:
Array[4474]** instead of **[Sat Feb 04 2017 14:16:51 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time), Fri May 05 2017 14:16:51 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)]** which doesn't set the proper domain for X axis.

[image]

Any sort of help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Could the issue be `datakey="T"`? You are parsing the date string when passing to `d3.extent`, but it's still a string when recharts looks up property `T` of each item, which might lead to strangeness when it tries to interpolate strings. Try processing your data first, parsing the date strings to date objects.

Comment: @Anko I tried doing that too. It doesn't works!!!

Comment: At this point, a [mcve] would help. It's hard to speculate what you mean by "it doesn't work".

Comment: @Anko Please could you show me an example by what you meant by Try processing your data first, parsing the date strings to date objects

Comment: I meant `da.forEach(function(d) { d.T = new Date(d.T) })`. But you said you had tried doing that?